# How do you do a string split on "\" in java?

Tags: java, io, filereader

I kept getting a file not found error in my java project, so I looked up the code for the filepath and used that:

```
File here = new File(".");
System.out.println(here.getAbsolutePath());
```

this worked once i switched the "\" with "/" and appended my file name to it.

I'm trying to do this through code, instead of going in and changing the "\" to "/" by hand, as this is an assignment. and it wont have the same file path.

[I've tried saving the files in everylevel (Project, Src, & package), but I cant get the FileReader to find it]

Comment: *"[URGENT]"*  'too localized'.

Comment: you can try: s = s.replace("\\", "/");

Comment: which operating system are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape Windows slashes in Java - add two slashes instead of one.

Use this:

```
String path = "c:\\foo\\bar";
```

instead of this:

```
String path = "c:\foo\bar";
```

Comment: Well this gives me: "C:\foo\bar\" but I need to change it to "C:/foo/bar". So i was going to use the split method to split on "\" and append it together with "/". Unless there's a better way of doing that?

Comment: @TheGandhi did you try my answer `s = s.replace("\\", "/");`?

Answer (score 0):

Simply write this for you´r String/Path

```
replace("/", "\\\\"); 
//or
replace("\\", "/");
```

Windows works with double \, but this won´t work with Linux for example if i am not totally wrong. The common way to write a path is a single /. This should work with every OS.

Answer (score 0):

I dont knw if it works or no but we tried this in CSharp to avoid continuous writing '\' (double backslash)..Here is the way to avoid double slash

```
String path="~@\c:\foo\bar";
```